# How to make a regular expression based on this criterion?

Tags: regex

My password should be: alphanumeric characters (uppercase and lowercase English letters, numbers, and symbols such as `@`, `#`, `*` and `&`)

How do make a regular expression for such rules?

I tried: `^\\s*[a-zA-Z0-9_\\-\\.]*\\s*$`

The value that gives the error: `45a$` and `1a@`

Comment: Welcome to SO. What have you tried already? Please read [ask].

Comment: Hello, I have "^\\s*[a-zA-Z0-9_\\-\\.]*\\s*$" at the moment

Comment: Does the password need to contain at least one character of each type of character? Do you really want to allow spaces at each end?

Comment: 1) No, do not need to contain at least one character of each type of character. 2) I think yes, will this create any problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
[A-Za-z0-9@#\*&]*
```

Comment: `*` does not need to be escaped in a character class

Comment: I would add `^...$`, otherwise a password such as `pw7!tem` would return two matches.

Comment: Probably, you want to set min and max number of symbols - for example, 3 and 10. In this case use `{3,10}` insteas of ending `*`.

Comment: Yes, I want to set min and max length. Thank u!